# Why does JSONObject not encode my class?

Tags: java, json, encoding, json-simple

```
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONAware;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.JSONValue;

public class JsonTest implements JSONAware {
private final int x, y;

public JsonTest(int x, int y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

@Override
public String toJSONString() {
    JSONArray arr = new JSONArray();
    arr.add(this.x);
    arr.add(this.y);
    return arr.toString();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JsonTest jtest = new JsonTest(4, 5);
    String test1 = JSONValue.toJSONString(jtest);
    System.out.println(test1); //this works as expected
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
    obj.put(jtest, "42");
    System.out.println(obj); //this doesn't
}
}
```

Gives as output:

> [4,5]
>
> {"it.integrasistemi.scegliInPianta.etc.JsonTest@3cb89838":"42"}

Instead of:

> [4,5]
>
> {[4,5]:"42"}

What am i missing?

My reference: http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/wiki/EncodingExamples#Example_6-1_-_Customize_JSON_outputs

Comment: `[4,5]` is no valid JSON identifier!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because `JSonTest` doesn't override the `toString()` method.

Add the following code to the `JSonTest` class:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return toJSONString(); 
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't "implements JSONAware" be the correct way to go in this cases? - http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/wiki/EncodingExamples#Example_6-1_-_Customize_JSON_outputs

Comment: `JSONAware` doesn't override the `toString()` method and `JSONObject` calls the `toString()` method (as evidently seen in your code example).

Comment: @FabioMariaCarlucci: implementing an interface does not automatically include a customized toString(), and `Object.toString()` will not do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Because only a String can be used as a key of a JSON object. So your jtest object is transformed to a String.

Comment: Because it's calling the object's `toString()` method.